# Highchairs Pie chart moving single data label

Tags: highcharts

As you can see by my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Bwata/5jkkn72m/) I am trying to off center the Highcharts pie chart, but the label for the large section is off to the left and cropped. Is there a way to shift it more to the top where there is room? I also want to be able to move the connector as well. If I have to I am willing to hardcode a location in the container as the size will never change.

code:

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
        },
        chart: {
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Myriad'
            }
        },
        colors: [
            'rgb(97,70,59)',
            'rgb(129,123,59)',
            'rgb(0,125,171)',
            'rgb(240,50,46)',
            'rgb(175,186,102)',
            'rgb(228,21,58)',
        ]
    });

    var options = {

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            align: 'top',
            type: 'pie'
        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                center: ['30%', '60%'],
                animation: false,
                borderWidth: 3,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    crop: false,
                    overflow: 'none',
                    softConnector: false,
                    connectorWidth: 2,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.key + "<br>" + this.percentage.toFixed(2) + '%';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        series : [],
    };

    var series = {
        data: [
            {
                type:'pie',
                name: 'Example 1',
                y: 5000
            },
            {
                type:'pie',
                name: 'Example 2',
                y: 2150
            },
            {
                type:'pie',
                name: 'Example 3',
                y: 3000
            },
            {
                type:'pie',
                name: 'Example 4',
                y: 8000
            },
            {
                type:'pie',
                name: 'Example 5',
                y: 5000
            },
            {
                type:'pie',
                name: 'Example 6',
                y: 50000
            }
        ],
        size: '85%', // added for the donut view
        innerSize: '75%', // updated for the donut view
    };

    options.series.push(series);
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At this moment this is default behavoir of chart. You can disable main dataLabels and use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) to add custom shapes like text or paths.

You can also post your suggestion in our [userVoice service](https://highcharts.uservoice.com) and vote for it.